# Does ol3-cesium accept DEM files?

Tags: 3d, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I'm using OpenLayers 3.6.0. I want to use [`ol3-cesium`](http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/). `Ol3-cesium` use [`cesium`](http://cesiumjs.org/) for glob visualization. I have a question:

**In ol3-cesium, Can I see Ups and downs of land? In other words Does it accept DEM files?**

Comment: Do you mean a terrain provider?

Comment: yes, Do ol3-cesium present a terrain provider?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes, but it has to be pre-processed into a different format because DEM files and other "raw" terrain data is not suitable for visualization.  The standard for Cesium is [quantized-mesh](https://cesiumjs.org/data-and-assets/terrain/formats/quantized-mesh-1.0.html), but we also support traditional height maps.  The premier application for processing terrain for Cesium is the [STK Terrain Server](http://www.agi.com/products/stk/terrain-server/), which is a commercial product.  There are some other open source projects, of various quality, which also attempt to generate terrain compatible with Cesium.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the Cesium cofounders and work for the company that makes STK Terrain Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard Cesium terrain provider, or if you have your own elevation data, you can serve it up through GeoServer and use: https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider